# SharePoint 2013 on high availability - Site collection created not appearing on warm standby farm

Tags: 2013, site-collection, central-administration, sql-server, disaster-recovery

We have got SharePoint 2013 on premise with a DR farm on Warm standby and SQL always on high availability. When i create a site collection in an existing content database (which is already added to an availability group), the site collection doesn't appear automatically on the DR farm. Makes sense because the config database is different for both active and DR farm

If i dismount and mount the database again in DR environment, I can see the site collection appearing in DR central admin.

I am not sure if this is the way it is supposed to work or is there some sort of limitation with SQL always on and creating site collection on existing database?
Can someone please confirm?
Appreciate your reply.
I tried googling but couldn't find much help online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following on the DR farm:

```
$db = Get-SPContentDatabase dbName
$db.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase()
```

Comment: Thanks heaps.. Works perfectly. For some reason I was getting "Connection Timeout Expired attempting to consume pre-login handshake" error message in a different environment.
Also in my test DR farm, content dbs in central admin are pointing to availability group of Active farm(which just contains the active farm's config db and central admin db) and I could still see the sites working in DR farm. Any idea what could be happening?